# Image gallery that refreshes page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, gallery, page-refresh

I want to build or find a image slider/gallery that will refresh the page whenever the next button is clicked (to increase page views/impressions). I know that it is possible to refresh the page on click with JavaScript or Jquery but the problem is that the JavaScript is reset and begins at the first slide. I read that it may be possible to achieve this by storing the active slide variable in a cookie. Does anyone know of a gallery that does this? or something similar that I could reference? or any other way I can achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add this function to your next button (when clicked):

```
location.reload();
```

Hope it solved the problem, best regards :)

**EDIT:** Sorry, yes it does reset the slide. What if you create an HTML gallery? you won't have any problem, and I find it easier / quickier... Sorry for not solving your problem...

Comment: An HTML gallery is not very pretty or user friendly though. I also cannot display ads on the image source page. Thank you for the suggestion though.